# Задача с методом java "hasZero()"

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки.
Условие задачи: Написать метод  hasZero(),который принимает int как input  и возвращает true, если введенное число содержит цифру 0 (например., 1810). Создать класс MagicSum, который используя метод hasZero() запрашивает в цикле до N ввод чисел и печатает сумму только тех введенных, которые не содержат цифру 0.

```
public static boolean hasZero(int n) {
        String s= n + "";
        if (s.indexOf("0") != -1)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int sum;
        Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int chislo = myinput.nextInt();
            if ( hasZero(chislo) )
                sum += chislo; 
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу ошибок кроме двух:

1. Не инициализирована переменная `sum`. Должно быть хотя бы `int sum = 0;`
2. На данный момент складываются числа, как раз-таки **имеющие** ноль. А раз нужно складывать числа их **не** содержащие, то надо исправить условие:

   ```
   if( !hasZero(chislo) )
       ^
   ```

Comment: Да, потом заметила, что не задала значение переменной. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Kristina если всё разрешилось и помогло - клацай галку слева)

Comment: 3-й пункт: скобка - конец цикла

Comment: @dgzargo да. точно

Comment: @Kristina кстати в методе `hasZero`  не обязательно ставить `else`. Потому что если `if` исполнится, то в любом случае код вернет `true` и дальше не пойдет.... а если пройдет это условие, то в любом случае пойдет исполнение дальше и можно просто написать `return false;` в конце метода